# Managed Package: Differences between quick actions and "Error: Cannot modify managed object: entity=QuickActionDefinition"

Tags: ant, package, quickaction, managed-package

I have got a managed package, which I install on developer org to test it. After installation I can surely see the differences between the quick actions, which I've on my testing org and on the org where I do create a package. The differences are in predefined values, fields on layouts and even required fields.

I have tried to retrieve these custom quick actions from the package org, and then deploy it to the testing org, but I encounter the error:

> Error: Cannot modify managed object: entity=QuickActionDefinition, component=09D0O00000453Nn, field=OptionsCreateFeedItem, state=installed".

My package.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Properto</fullName>
    <apiAccessLevel>Unrestricted</apiAccessLevel>
    <namespacePrefix>myPackageNamespace</namespacePrefix>
    <types>
        <members>ObjectName.QuickActionName</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

I would appreciate all sugestions, answers and help.
Maybe there is a way to have always "fresh" quick actions on testing org after installation or there is a way to deploy it somehow.

---

my package.xml

```
fullName Properto fullName
apiAccessLevel Unrestricted apiAccessLevel
namespacePrefix myPackageNamespace namespacePrefix
types
    members ObjectName.QuickActionName members
    nameQuickAction name
types
```

Comment: Make sure to use code formatting (indent by four spaces) so that your XML tags are rendered in your question. (That's why you were getting a blank).

Comment: @Mateusz any chance you found a resolution to this issue?